# find right ruby version for gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I got the issue multiple times that I can't run a rails project because I get the message from rubymine:

```
    gem 'yada yada' is not available in the project sdk ruby version xxx.
```

... is there a way to find out the right Ruby version to use from the gemfile, even if someone does not specify it explicitly in the gemfile?

Concretely I can't run the following projects if s.o. wants to help here... (1) https://github.com/becky000/sample_app
[2] https://github.com/lobsters/lobsters
[3] https://github.com/paulorja/rts-web-rails

Maybe someone gets the same issues while trying these ones to get to run.

Comment: Take a look at rvm

Answer (score 0):

The lobster app has a [`.ruby-version`](https://github.com/lobsters/lobsters/blob/master/.ruby-version) file in its root which is a common way to declare the Ruby version the app is depending on.

For the others apps, you will probably need to contact the maintainers or investigate on Rubygems the dependencies for every gem that fails to install (e.q. [`yada yada`](https://rubygems.org/search?query=yada+yada)).